# Did contractor put in the cherry wood I ordered it doesn’t look like the sample

Tags: hardwood

Just had engineered wood installed on steps.  Was supposed to be cherry but it looks like oak and it has not changed color after a month even with a uv light.

Comment: Not quite sure, but the engineered wood might have a number on it(maybe only on the package) that matches the sample type.  That number should at least be on the invoice/sales receipt.  Very seldom that it would only have cherry or oak as a full description of the product.

Answer (score 2):

Can't begin to answer whether this is or isn't cherry without photos. (I initially suggested photos of edge grain and end grain too, but I just noticed that it's engineered lumber so those probably won't be helpful.)

Color change in woods can take years (and can be affected by what finish has been applied). I suggest you accept that natural processes run on nature's timeline, and that deeply colored cherry is valued precisely because it *does* take time to develop. You could refinish it and stain it, of course, but then what's the point in using cherry?

Also, note that "a UV light" is generally long-wave UVA; the online references I've seen to using UV to darken cherry used short-wave UVB, which  is more energetic -- and for that reason more dangerous; you should not be working with UVB without safety equipment to keep it out of your eyes.

Comment: How can I attach a photo?

Comment: Edit the question. At the top of the editing box, there's an icon that looks like mountains. Clicking that lets you insert photos.

Comment: You also might bet better answers about aging cherry wood over on woodworkers stack exchange.com